# Wamp 403 fobidden when accessing get the a JS file from an HTML PAGE

Tags: javascript, wamp, wampserver

I have a website in WWW in wamp, a simple HTML file with a call to a JS file. On my local machine in www testing in a Chrome I receive an error  403 fobidden.

I have tried to setup the permission in Windows Explorere but no success.

Any idea? thanks

Comment: Have you ensured the WAMP server can be accessed by other network hosts?

Comment: Yes, I can access others website in www

Comment: Yes the page is accessibile... very odd...

Comment: Can you please clarify if you receive the 403 on the whole HTML page or just the JS file? Where are the HTML and JS files located relative to the webroot? Are you able to access the directory listing of your web root if there is no index file?

Comment: I receive 403 on the JS file, html is ok, hey are both relative to the web root....yes I am able to access the web root if not files